# Exporting svg with foreignObject tag as an Image using PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, image, svg, export

Is there a way to export an `<svg>` tag containing `<foreignObject>` as an Image using PHP or Java? I have tried https://github.com/sampula/SVG.toDataURL but it does not support foreignObject.

The only reason I want to be able to encode the foreignObject as to base64 is because that the foreignObject tag contains some HTML and an image inside.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: SVG is XML.  Have you tried XSLT?  It will have no problem extracting any part of the SVG you want.  You can certainly call XSLT from Java using Saxon or whatever XSLT processor you like.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but, yes I've successfully done it using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)